# SQL Server Select Not Returning All Rows

Tags: sql-server, select

I have run into a very strange problem where a query is returning most rows but not all of them. If I add an addition condition to my where clause, the missing row appears.

Below is my query:

```
SELECT T1.Table1ID,
    SUM(ISNULL([T4].Qty,0)) TotalQty
FROM dbo.Table1 (NOLOCK) T1
    INNER JOIN [dbo].Table2 (NOLOCK) T2 ON T1.Table2ID = T2.Table2ID
    INNER JOIN [dbo].Table3 (NOLOCK) T3 ON T2.DocTypeID = T3.DocTypeID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Table4 (NOLOCK) T4 ON T4.Table1ID = T1.Table1ID
WHERE T3.is1 = 0
GROUP BY T1.Table1ID
ORDER BY T1.Table1ID
```

This returns all rows except for the one with T1.Table1ID = 185671. If I add it as a filter like such:

```
SELECT T1.Table1ID,
    SUM(ISNULL([T4].Qty,0)) TotalQty
FROM dbo.Table1 (NOLOCK) T1
    INNER JOIN [dbo].Table2 (NOLOCK) T2 ON T1.Table2ID = T2.Table2ID
    INNER JOIN [dbo].Table3 (NOLOCK) T3 ON T2.DocTypeID = T3.DocTypeID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Table4 (NOLOCK) T4 ON T4.Table1ID = T1.Table1ID
WHERE T3.is1 = 0
    AND T1.Table1ID = 185671
GROUP BY T1.Table1ID
ORDER BY T1.Table1ID
```

Now the row shows. Any ideas?

EDIT: New query after removing NOLOCK hint.

```
SELECT T1.Table1ID,
    SUM(ISNULL([T4].Qty,0)) TotalQty
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN [dbo].Table2 T2 ON T1.Table2ID = T2.Table2ID
    INNER JOIN [dbo].Table3 T3 ON T2.DocTypeID = T3.DocTypeID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Table4 T4 ON T4.Table1ID = T1.Table1ID
WHERE T3.is1 = 0
    AND T1.Table1ID = 185671
GROUP BY T1.Table1ID
ORDER BY T1.Table1ID
```

Comment: And I don't believe you.

Comment: I dont believe you neither. But is easy to debug. Remove the `group by`  and aggregation function and try to find the `185671` row. Without the filter `T1.Table1ID = 185671` how many rows are there?

Comment: Without the aggregate or group by, the rows show. Why would they disappear when using those?

Comment: You seem to be concerned about the accuracy of your query, yet you have littered the NOLOCK hint everywhere. That hint can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ If you care about accuracy get rid of that thing.

Comment: I have eliminated the NOLOCK hint and tried the aggregate and it still is not showing without the filter.

Comment: Is this really your query? Or did you remove some complexity for posting while also changing object names? Are you really selecting from tables in the current database or are you selecting from views or synonyms?

Comment: The complexity has remained the same. I just renamed the tables / aliases for posting. These are tables and not views.

Comment: Also @JuanCarlosOropeza there are 129300 rows returned without the aggregate, group by, or filter T1.Table1ID = 185671.

Comment: @JAnderson; It is a little work, but to test your sanity you could push the results of your non-filtered query into a temp table, then do a query on the temp table with the 'and' statement back in place. I suspect you will find you are just missing it in the results. If not, you got something interesting here. On easy mistake to make is that your Query tool might be limiting the results you see (say to the top 1000) for performance - hard to be sure, but throwing out ideas.

Comment: If your query without group by has the id, then your query with group by also have the id. As simple like that. As @SteveJ as suggest create a table with that query and then try the group by and aggregated over that subtable. You should see your missing id there.

Comment: The only thing I can Imagine is if you use a `LEFT JOIN` some where, but I dont see one in your query.

Comment: What's the type of `Table1ID`?

Comment: I have fixed the issue although unfortunately I don't know yet why it worked. The query I have been using and providing to you all was the body of a view, which has schemabinding on. That view had a unique clustered index on the Table1ID, which is an INT. As soon as I deleted the index, even the original query is working as expected now. The recommendation to try inserting the non-grouped nor aggregated information into a temp table helped get me to this conclusion. I had been seeing that even by calling the view, I was getting a similar issue where it worked with the filter and didn't without